# How to scope ViewModels properly?

Tags: architecture, android

I am trying to wrap my head around the new Android Architecture Components, specifically the ViewModel.

My impression is that a Fragment should not know about what Activity or Fragment it is owned by, so that it can be used in different contexts of the application. The examples seem to contradict this by declaring the ViewModel scope directly in the Fragment, rather than the Fragment owner:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SomeViewModel.class);
```

I would like to be able to use this Fragment in a Master/Detail configuration, where both share the same state (i.e. ViewModel instance), as well as inside a ViewPager, where all Fragments require separate state (i.e. separate ViewModel instances). I would expect the Fragment owner to dictate the scope, which does not seem to be supported with this approach.

A workaround I came up with could be to optionally pass in a configured ViewModelProvider to explicitly broaden the scope of a ViewModel if necessary (e.g. in the Master/Detail configuration) and have separate ViewModels by default:

```
final ViewModelProvider viewModelProvider;
if (viewModelProviderOverride != null) {
    viewModelProvider = viewModelProviderOverride;
} else {
    viewModelProvider = ViewModelProviders.of(this);
}

viewModel = viewModelProvider.get(SomeViewModel.class);
```

This way, the owner can decide whether multiple Fragments will share their state or not. I haven't fully thought this through yet, but it seems kind of fishy, since nothing close to it seems to be hinted at in the docs. I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: you want different `ViewModel`s for different `Fragment` instances? then use `ViewModelProvider#get(String key, Class<T> modelClass)`

Comment: @pskink I may have been a little unclear, sorry about that. My issue is that having `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())` in the fragment couples it to the parent activity and prevents using the fragment in a standalone fashion (i.e. `ViewModelProviders.of(this)`) in other places. I am questioning whether the fragment should be the one to decide who owns the state it is working with. It appears to me that the owner of the fragment (either the containing activity or another parent fragment) should be responsible for this choice. Does this clarify things?

Comment: well, `ViewModelProviders#of` methods are just utilities that can be used in most cases, if you need more control, you can always use one of two `ViewModelProvider` constructors, either passing `ViewModelStoreOwner` interface (for example implemented by `Application` or some singleton) or `ViewModelStore` directly if you have one, the drawback of it is you have also to pass `ViewModelProvider.Factory` but here you can use one of existing `ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory` or `ViewModelProviders.DefaultFactory`

Comment: @pskink I am fine with creating my own `ViewModelProvider`, but I was suspicious of passing it into the fragment instead of requesting it inside of the fragment, since nothing of the sort is ever done in the corresponding docs. Do you see any downside to just exposing a public setter for the, `ViewModelProvider` on the fragment?

Answer (score 2):

Saying `viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SomeViewModel.class);` means that you would like the state of the `ViewModel` to be scoped to the Activity. If you would not like the Fragment to be scoped to the activity you can just call `viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModel.class);`. Now all you do is `if (shareState)` then call the first and if not call the second.