# Loading URL in WebView from Button Click in BottomSheetDialogFragment via Data-Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, webview, viewmodel, bottom-sheet

### 0. Problem

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858720/implementing-two-way-data-binding-webview-using-mvvm-in-kotlin) question by gave me the idea to implement the Data Binding Library for the purpose of opening a Link in a Webview-Fragment on click of a Button in a Bottom Sheet Fragment.

I was able to implement the Data Binding as seen in the other Question ([Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59858720/implementing-two-way-data-binding-webview-using-mvvm-in-kotlin), but the WebView doesn't load the new URL when a Button is clicked in said Bottom Sheet Fragment. I get the feedback from the console that the Button was clicked and the LiveData was changed though.
So, I thought the WebView does reload automatically when the LiveData changes but that doesn't seem to be the case...so I do not see my Error and not sure if I implemented everything correctly.

*Hopefully someone can help me.*

---

### 1. Respective Classes

#### 1.1. WebViewFragment

```
    class WebviewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = WebviewFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: WebViewViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val binding: FragmentMainWebviewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_main_webview, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WebViewViewModel::class.java)

        binding.webViewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled", "JavascriptInterface")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        webView = webViewMain
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    }
}
```

#### 1.2. WebViewModel

```
    class WebViewViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val webViewUrl = MutableLiveData<String>().apply{ value = "file:///android_asset/html_files/gallery_page.html" }

    companion object WebViewUrlLoader {
        @BindingAdapter("loadUrl")
        @JvmStatic
        fun  WebView.setUrl(url: String) {
            this.loadUrl(url)
        }
    }
}
```

#### 1.3. WebView Layout (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="webViewModel"
            type="com.example.ui.main.webview.WebViewViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_screen_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainFragmentGalleryView"
        >
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:loadUrl="@{webViewModel.webViewUrl}"
            android:paddingBottom="52dp" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

#### 1.4. BottomSheet Fragment

```
class BottomSheetFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private var fragmentView: View? = null
    private lateinit var viewModel: WebViewViewModel

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = BottomSheetFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_modal_bottom_sheet, container, false)
        return fragmentView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WebViewViewModel::class.java)
        initView()
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.Theme_NoWiredStrapInNavigationBar
    }

    private val mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback: BottomSheetCallback = object : BottomSheetCallback() {
        var isBottomSheetUp = false
        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
            //TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                isBottomSheetUp = false
                dismiss()
            } else isBottomSheetUp = true
        }

    }

    override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog, style: Int) {
        //super.setupDialog(dialog, style)
        val contentView =
            View.inflate(context,
                R.layout.view_modal_bottom_sheet, null)
        dialog.setContentView(contentView)
        val layoutParams =
            (contentView.parent as View).layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        val behavior = layoutParams.behavior
        if (behavior != null && behavior is BottomSheetBehavior<*>) {
            behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback)
        }
    }

    private fun initView() {

        action_my_pictures.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.webViewUrl.value = "https://www.google.com/"
            Log.d("BottomSheet", "Button 1 Clicked ${viewModel.webViewUrl.value}")
        }
        action_favorites.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.webViewUrl.value = "https://www.hotmail.de/"
            Log.d("BottomSheet", "Button 2 Clicked ${viewModel.webViewUrl.value}")

        }
        action_ranking.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.webViewUrl.value = "https://amazon.com/"
            Log.d("BottomSheet", "Button 3 Clicked ${viewModel.webViewUrl.value}")

        }
        action_hall_of_fame.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.webViewUrl.value = "https://m.daum.net/"
            Log.d("BottomSheet", "Button 4 Clicked ${viewModel.webViewUrl.value}")

        }
        action_liked_pictures.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.webViewUrl.value = "https://m.nate.com/"
            Log.d("BottomSheet", "Button 5 Clicked ${viewModel.webViewUrl.value}")

        }
        action_events.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.webViewUrl.value = "https://www.danawa.com/"
            Log.d("BottomSheet", "Button 6 Clicked ${viewModel.webViewUrl.value}")

        }
        action_close_bottom_sheet.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

#### 1.5. BottomSheet Layout (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="webViewModel"
            type="com.example.ui.main.webview.WebViewViewModel" />
    </data>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bottomNavigationViewBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="auto"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:behavior_fitToContents="true">


[7 Image/Icons as Buttons]
 Example:
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/action_my_pictures"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_my_pictures"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_my_pictures_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="My Gallery"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

### 2. LOG output (for Button Clicks)

```
D/BottomSheet: Button 1 Clicked https://www.google.com/
D/BottomSheet: Button 2 Clicked https://www.hotmail.de/
D/BottomSheet: Button 3 Clicked https://amazon.com/
D/BottomSheet: Button 4 Clicked https://m.daum.net/
D/BottomSheet: Button 4 Clicked https://m.daum.net/
D/BottomSheet: Button 5 Clicked https://m.nate.com/
D/BottomSheet: Button 6 Clicked https://www.danawa.com/
```

---

**A lot of thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in scope of life that you provide for viewModel.
Currently you code looks like this:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WebViewViewModel::class.java)
```

This code is invoked inside two different fragments, and because ViewModelProvider is initialized with current instance of fragment (this). Your view model is only available in this scope (fragment scope). So at the end for each fragment you will get new ViewModel. To share ViewModel between fragments you should use different approach:

1. Instantiate ViewModelProvider with activity. (ViewModel will be share across all fragments inside activity)
2. Instantiate ViewModelProvider with parentFragment. (ViewModel will be shared across all child fragments)

sample:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(WebViewViewModel::class.java)

viewModel = ViewModelProvider(parentFragment).get(WebViewViewModel::class.java)
```

please also check:

[How to scope ViewModels properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45993990/how-to-scope-viewmodels-properly)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders

Comment: Splendid! That solved the problem. I was suspecting the Lifecycle-Owner to be wrong but it didn't help to set it to activity. However, instantiating the ViewModelProvider with the Activity (Single Activity) solved the problem!